# Quartz jobPersistenceException with hsqldb

Tags: quartz-scheduler, hsqldb

I'm trying to run a scheduler using quartz. I use HSQLDB (version 2.2.7 ). But I get following exception;

> Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store job: data exception: string data, right truncation [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: string data, right truncation]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1132)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$3.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1071)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3716)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3788)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:90)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3712)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJobAndTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1059)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:822)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:243)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at com.aepona.ase.services.terminalstatus.utils.SimpleTriggerExample.afterPropertiesSet(SimpleTriggerExample.java:32)[320:com.aepona.ase.services.terminalstatus:3.0.7.VFB-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)[439:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)[439:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 14 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: string data, right truncation
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)[315:org.hsqldb.hsqldb:2.2.7]
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)[315:org.hsqldb.hsqldb:2.2.7]
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)[315:org.hsqldb.hsqldb:2.2.7]
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)[315:org.hsqldb.hsqldb:2.2.7]
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102)[301:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp:1.2.2.7]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.insertJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:530)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1126)[475:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz:1.8.6.1]

anyone familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using `quartz-scheduler 1.8.6`. The DB script comes with it for HSQLDB uses `BINARY` data type in `qrtz_job_details`, `qrtz_triggers`, `qrtz_calendars` and `qrtz_blob_triggers` tables. I just change `BINARY` to `BLOB` and problem solved.